# Camera2 would not show preview using AutoFitTextureView

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am having an issue with the camera2 preview by using AutoFitTextureView. After executing this code, the layout shows up normally. The camera preview would not show up. I have the permission to use the camera. Before this I wrote

```
setContentView(mTextureView)
```

this  worked. Thank you in advance.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextureView = new AutoFitTextureView(this);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}
```

SurfaceTexture

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    openCamera(width, height);
}

public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
}

public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    closeCamera();
    return true;
}

public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
}
```

AutoFitTextureView

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mRatioWidth = width;
        mRatioHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000" >

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_take_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextureView in your layout file is not automatically mTextureView in your code. It's an entirely separate TextureView, which you can get a reference to via the usual [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)) method.

If you want to use the AutoFitTextureView in your layout, you have to actually call it that, which takes a bit more work since you have to tell the layout system about AutoFixTextureViews.

Alternatively, you can add the mTextureView you create to your layout manually, by finding the FrameLayout and then adding a child to it.

These are all standard Android UI creation topics, not camera specific, so you should be able to find plenty of resources about creating custom views on Android or how to do a mix of XML and programmatic UI layout.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I would learn much more about layout in android.

Answer (score -1):

By adding 
    `init(){}`method to AutoFitTextureView class
and
`findViewById` to MainActivity class.

And Deleting `mTextureView = new AutoFitTextureView(this);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);`.

You also have to change the XML file from TextureView to "package name".AutoFitTextureView.

Before this change, there is no method that executes TextureView via AutoFitTextureView.

For those who are new to Android and cannot understand, check this Youtube video:  https://youtu.be/sb9OEl4k9Dk.

I hope this helps.